# zipalign doesn't change the apk file

Tags: android, optimization

```
zipalign -v 4 input.apk output.apk
```

several times for my changing application and the corresponding md5 from both input and output has always been the same, so they're the very same file. Isn't this tool suppose to perform certain optimizations, hence modify the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it was already executed by your build process (i.e. ANT).

Also, pls read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/zipalign.html for more details.

Comment: Good point I'm using eclipse/ADT tools, maybe there's something in the preferences ...

Comment: It won't do anything if there's nothing to do (either because it was already run, or because you got lucky and everything just happened to land the right way).  You can pass the "-c" flag to zipalign to check the alignment of a file.

Comment: Agree with fadden. Esp when using Eclipse/ADT, zipalign might have been executed already.